# How to add zero-padding to a single Span<byte> without allocate memory?

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management

I have a method to convert `Span<byte>` to `int`:

```
int ConvertToInt32(Span<byte> buffer)
{
    if (buffer.Length != 4)
    {
        // add zero-padding to the buffer
    }

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer);
    // or MemoryMarshal....
}
```

If the input parameter (`buffer`) length is 4, so the conversion works, but if it has less than 4 bytes it doesn't.
I'm looking for a non-allocating method to do this.
So how can I add zero-padding to the `buffer` before conversion, or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can allocate on stack with [`stackalloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc) which should be cheaper then allocating on the heap and is usual approach in high-performance scenarios AFAIK:

```cs
Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[3] {0,0,1};
if (buffer.Length != 4)
{
    Span<byte> interimBuffer = stackalloc byte[4];
    // ..
}
```

Note that you can just convert to type with corresponding size and then cast to `int`:

```cs
if (buffer.Length == 2)
{
    var int16 = (int)BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer);
}
```

But due to branching it can have worse performance.

Also do not forget about endianness of computer's architecture [as written in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int#examples).

Comment: `stackalloc` is a great idea. I wonder how the performance would compare to a static array. The cast to int (or byte if one byte) based on length would work. How would you propose to handle three bytes? A byte and an int, and combine them? Again, endianness rears its ugly head.

Comment: stackalloc is a great idea. I wonder how the performance would compare to a static array. Casting to int from `ToInt16` or, I assume, `ToInt8` should work. How would you propose to handle three bytes? A byte and an int, and combine them? Although endianness rears its ugly head again.

Comment: @JimMischel _"I wonder how the performance would compare to a static array"_ - test it, I suggest using BenchmarkDotNet. In single threaded processing potentially it can be faster, but usually you don't want to be limited with one thread. _"How would you propose to handle three bytes?"_ - the same way you handle every non-4 bytes case now)

Comment: I hadn't considered the multithreading case. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

You could waste four bytes on a static buffer:

```
// buffer used for converting fewer than 4 bytes
private static byte convertBuffer[] = new byte[4];
int ConvertToInt32(Span<byte> buffer)
{
    if (buffer.Length != 4)
    {
        // copy the bytes from buffer to convertBuffer
        // and then . . .
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer);
    }

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer);
    // or MemoryMarshal....
}
```

The question here will be where to copy the bytes. Do you pad left or pad right? As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-7.0) says:

> The order of bytes in the array must reflect the endianness of the computer system's architecture. For more information, see the Remarks section of BitConverter.

In truth, that 4-byte buffer will likely require more than 4 bytes, what with allocation overhead and such. I'd figure somewhere between 12 and 24 bytes, depending on if you're running on the 32-bit or 64-bit runtime. Still, it prevents having to do a memory allocation every time you use it.

The only other way I can think of is to write a loop that'll do the conversion: basically, re-create the logic of `BitConverter.ToInt32()`, but modified to handle fewer than 4 bytes. That's not too tough, but again you need to make allowances for the endianness of the computer. If you're interested in how `BitConverter` works, take a look at [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs).